# Can we use ContentObserver to observe database field changes? (Not insertion and deletion)

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, contentobserver

Here is my situation. I want to know if any SMS in our device has changed from unread to read. So I am using this ContentObserver to observe DB changes.

```
this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms/"),true,new TextContentObserver(new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
```

It works perfectly and I get the callback when the state changes. But there is no way for me to find which SMS changed. I just get a blind ping saying SMS DB has been touched. Is there a way to find out from ContentObserver which record was updated/inserted/deleted?

**EDIT:
TextContentObserver is just a class to get the callback.**

```
class TextContentObserver extends ContentObserver {


    public TextContentObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        //How to find what DB change happened?
        //insert/delete/update?

    }

}
```

Comment: what is TextContentObserver? do you override onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) in TextContentObserver?

Comment: updated the question to include the info.

Comment: "But there is no way for me to find which SMS changed." you have **Uri uri** in onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri)

Comment: that will only have an extra param which will be the Uri which is "content://sms". How can I use that to identify what changed?

Comment: if the uri doesn't identify your resource, then use a **CursorJoiner**

Comment: when using CursorJoiner Result.LEFT ususually points to old data and Result.RIGHT points to new data